# Building error of iOS app to an ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Currently Im making an iOS app and got an **error** to build the app to **iPad**.

I have 2 **iMacs**, on first iMac, building succeeds. but doesn't succeed on Second iMac.The second iMac's documents, apps, user accounts, and settings are the same to the first iMac because I set up the second iMac using migration assistant, so I expected not to have any trouble.
Some information says that there are kind of parent-children relationship between Mac PCs, so I tried to export certification from the first iMac and install to the Second iMac, but It didn't work.

I also tried to make another provisioning profile, change settings of Code Signing in Build Settings, clean, or reboot Xcode, but nothing worked.
Below is error messages I've got.

> Feb 12 20:20:34 ec1 streaming_zip_conduit[215] :
>   LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder
>    jp.co.worksap.E-OmniSupport03
>   <(null) *Not found in database*> Feb 12 20:20:34 ec1
>   streaming_zip_conduit[215] : LaunchServices: Not creating
>   progress for 
>   jp.co.worksap.E-OmniSupport03 <(null) *Not found in database*> since
>   it is not a placeholder. Feb 12 20:20:34 ec1 installd[47] :
>   0x16e1bb000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]:
>   Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/E-OmniSupport.app" type
>   Developer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by streaming_zip_conduit
>   (pid 215) Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1 installd[47] : 0x16e087000
>   -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing  Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1 profiled[85] : (Note )
>   MC: Provisioning profiles changed Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1 profiled[85]
>   : (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust... Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1
>   securityd[86] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain
>   entitlements: no stored taskRef found Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1
>   securityd[86] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain
>   entitlements: no stored taskRef found Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1 installd[47]
>   :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>   Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1 securityd[86] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1 securityd[86] : 
>   secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
>   taskRef found Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1 installd[47] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Feb 12
>   20:20:35 ec1 securityd[86] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements
>   MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found Feb 12 20:20:35
>   ec1 securityd[86] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING
>   keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1
>   installd[47] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName
>   SubjectCommonName] Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1 installd[47] : MIS:
>   unrecognized status -67049 from codesigning library Feb 12 20:20:35
>   ec1 installd[47] : 0x16e087000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier
>   _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 142: Failed to verify code signature of
>   /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2KUwcn/extracted/E-OmniSupport.app/Frameworks/SCLAlertView.framework
>   : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.) Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1
>   installd[47] : 0x16e087000 -[MIInstaller
>   performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed Feb 12
>   20:20:35 ec1 streaming_zip_conduit[215] : 0x16e12f000
>   __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify
>   code signature of
>   /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2KUwcn/extracted/E-OmniSupport.app/Frameworks/SCLAlertView.framework
>   : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)"
>   UserInfo={LibMISErrorNumber=-402620415,
>   LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=142,
>   FunctionName=+[MICodeSigningVerifier
>   _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of
>   /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2KUwcn/extracted/E-OmniSupport.app/Frameworks/SCLAlertView.framework
>   : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)} Feb 12 20:20:35 ec1
>   streaming_zip_conduit[215] : ERROR:
>   MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil Feb 12
>   20:20:35 ec1 streaming_zip_conduit[215] :
>   __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:274: Failed to install application at
>   file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/E-OmniSupport.app/ : Error
>   Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620415,
>   ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of
>   /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2KUwcn/extracted/E-OmniSupport.app/Frameworks/SCLAlertView.framework
>   : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)}

Can you come up with anything to this message?
I hope someone helps me out.

Comment: Are you using proxy based system, have login account on domain or you have admin rights?

Comment: Im not totally sure what you meant, but Im logging in the same account which exists in the first iMac ( account information is also copied to the second iMac from the first iMac). So there might be a conflict between accounts. Im gonna try to make another account in the second iMac and build.